# [Blender2.8]When getting vertex belongs to vertex group

Tags: python, vertex-groups

I tried to get a vertex belongs to a vertex group like below. But nothing is returned.

```
import bpy

obj = boy.data.objects['Cube']
obj.select_set(True)
obj.vertex_groups.new(name='Group')

vertexgroup = obj.vertex_group.get('Group')
for v in obj.data.vertices:
    for g in v.groups:
         if g.group == vertexgroup.index:
             print(v)
```

to check if it's working I called print(), but nothing happened.What is wrong?? can anyone help me??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No verts are assigned to the group**

The trivial error in question code (`bpy` not `boy`) aside, you have not assigned any vertices to the new group.

Test script, assigns verts indices 0, 1 and 4 to the new vertex group of object named "Cube" if it exists.

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.data.objects.get("Cube")

if obj:
    vg = obj.vertex_groups.new(name='Group')
    # need to assign some verts to group
    vg.add([0, 1, 4], 1.0, 'REPLACE')
    for v in obj.data.vertices:
        for g in v.groups:
             if g.group == vg.index:
                 print(v.index)
```

If you already have a vg named "Group" and wish to use it, or create if non existent

```
vg = (obj.vertex_groups.get('Group')
     or obj.vertex_groups.new(name='Group'))
```

Feel it is important to note that question code

```
obj.vertex_groups.new(name='Group')
vertexgroup = obj.vertex_group.get('Group')
```

will work "as expected" only when there is no prior vg named "Group".  Other wise the newly added group will be named "Group.001", "Group.002" etc etc, yet you are only ever getting the one originally named "Group".

Comment: Thank you!! I got it!!